# Set Index as Integers with Mixed Types

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': [1.0,2.0,"A"]})
DF

   COL1
0   1
1   2
2   A
```

If 1 and 2 are floats and I set 'COL1' as the index, I get:

```
DF = DF.set_index('COL1')
DF

COL1
1.0
2.0
A
```

How can I manipulate the new index such that it only contains integers with no decimals (1 and 2) with the string ('A') in a mixed-type column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dumb question (not `pandas` user): Since when is `'A'` an integer? Also, would it not make sense to generate the index column from the mixed type column so it can be converted to uniform type and indexed properly, while preserving the original values of the mixed type column?

Comment: Hi, I just modified the question for clarity. I meant to say that I need a mixed-type column with the numbers being integers yet with the string still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to convert to ints in cases it is possible, you should probably use try and except, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': [1.0,2.0,"A"]})

def ToInt(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except:
        pass
    return x

DF.index = [ToInt(x) for x in DF.COL1]
DF
```